# Running a custom Windows Ce image in emulator

Tags: windows-ce, emulation

I need to write a software which uses custom features of Windows CE and debug it using an emulator. I have Platform Builder installed and all the necessary tools. I use OS designer to create the image. How should I set up Visual Studio so the image is loaded onto emulator? How do I debug my program? I was looking on the internet for this, but very little information is available.

Comment: You are asking 2 things here right? 1.How do you deploy the OS image to the emulator and 2. How do you deploy and debug a custom made program?            Please specify the Windows-CE version. I can only help with CE 6 for example...

Comment: It would be nice to post the links to the Virtual lab you referred to in the comment below for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've created an Emulator image using the Emulator BSP, then simply roll an SDK and install it.  That will add the emulator to your list of targets and wire everything into Studio for you.

Comment: I managed to create custom image in the Emulator and run it. For Novice, the process is fairly difficult. Luckily, Microsoft Virtual Lab had some tutorials on this which worked for me.